# How to use group by without losing the non-null details

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT item_id,
 (CASE WHEN cat_level="1" THEN cat_name ELSE "" END) AS category,
 (CASE WHEN cat_level="2" THEN cat_name ELSE "" END) AS sub_cat,
FROM item
```

The result :

```
|  item id  |   category    |    sub_cat   |
|    01     |transportation |              |
|    01     |               |     car      |
```

When I add `group by item_id`, the result becomes :

```
|  item id  |   category    |    sub_cat   |
|    01     |transportation |              |
```

But how to show the following?

```
|  item id  |   category    |    sub_cat   |
|    01     |transportation |     car      |
```

Comment: Just curious to know, how do you have item_id two times? Shouldn't `ID` be a primary key?? Probably your database design in wrong. Anyways, I am not attempting to answer the question as there is a good answer already. I just wanted to highlight the potential issue with the design which may bite your back in the long run.

Comment: They have category_id as their primary key, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregate function, like `Max` (and remove the `ELSE ""` from the `CASE`):

```
SELECT   item_id,
         Max(CASE WHEN cat_level="1" THEN cat_name END) AS category,
         Max(CASE WHEN cat_level="2" THEN cat_name END) AS sub_cat,
FROM     item
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help~